# How to freeze the Toolbar at the top of the activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar

I'm trying to pin my toolbar at the top just like a normal 'Action Bar' just like when u click on a twitter post the toolbar up top stays there no matter how much u scroll down.

I found a lot of guides on "how to make the Toolbar collapse and other cool effects" but what i want from it, is to act as an Action bar and stay at the top, is there a simple way of accomplishing that ? without the use of (CoordinatorLayout, CollapsingToolbarLayout, ...) ?

Comment: um yeah that is the default, unless you nest it in the content layout

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thank you so much dude, yeah it was nested in the layout, it works like a charm now <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can pin your toolbar at the top of the activity for that you have to create a layout file named `toolbar_layout`like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarStyle"/>
```

And in the activity layout i.e `activity_main` file include it as like this:-

```
<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And after that design accordingly the layout

Cheers Happy Coding.

Comment: @merik :- is your problem solved or not by this anwser

Comment: ty mate, i had a scroll view then a constraint layout and my 'include' was inside that constraint layout, and when i wrapped them all in a linear layout and put the include inside the linear layout instead, just like u mentioned ^^^, it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your layout xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Your content here -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

or put `RecyclerView` instead of `ScrollView + LinearLayout` if you have a list

Comment: really no need for NestedScrollView here

Comment: It depends what is the height of your content. I described the case where a lot of content

Comment: *It depends* - not really. If you don't have a collapsingtoolbarlayout you should use regular scrollview